# Android layout inconsistency

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have a layout that is being displayed in two different layouts. First one is being displayed in a `LinearLayout` and it behaves as expected:

[image]

However, when this layout is part of a listview, the textview is not centered:

[image]

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <com.parse.ParseImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">
            <View
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_source"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Small"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fire"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_viewCount"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pin"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pin"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pin"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/pin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The textView that I am referring to is at the bottom with id `comment_tv`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try placing both image and text inside another relative layout which is a sure shot solution also changing android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" to marginTop also seems sensible for your layout

Comment: make gravity of textview as center_vertical

Comment: @IllegalArgument no luck placing it inside another relative layout

Comment: @AM tried but that doesn't work either

Comment: @0xSina let me try I have used it in my project and it works. heres another approach try setting the image as background of your textview I have used this too and its working for me

Comment: @IllegalArgument that kind of works, but text is not aligned in the center  of the image

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with your image and this is my result with underlying code. Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/sample"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="12"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And heres a snapshot of this code:
[image]

Comment: This works ONLY if your background image is symmetrical (square). Try this: http://i.imgur.com/nH1V7gH.png

Answer (score 0):

Your pin+text inside a relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pin"/>
  <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/comment_tv"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@id/pin"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp" //set this higher if you need
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" //if this text will be not in the center 
    //you can use the "layout_marginLeft" to put whatever you want
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This should but the text on the spot you want